# In lead conversion page, instead of '--None--' option for Account Name field. I want to pre-populate existing account

Tags: lead-conversion

Detailed requirement:
I have Account lookup field(Field Name is "Existing_Account__c") on Lead object. In lead conversion page salesforce by default displays "--None--" option for Account Name. 
But my business requirement is that- Instead of --None-- option I have to pre-populate account present in custom field Existing_Account__c. So that whenever users click on Convert button Account Name should have valid account instead of --None-- option. [image]

Comment: is it classic or lightning?

Answer (score 0):

If its classic you can do URL hacking as mentioned [here](http://pragmaticforce.blogspot.com/2011/10/custom-lead-convert-buttonmore-url.html):

You have to use a custom lead convert button , and then URL inject the lead field's as param. The formula for the Button will be like:

```
/lead/leadconvert.jsp?retURL=%2F003%2Fo&id={!Lead.Id}&accid={!Lead.Existing_Account__c}&tsk5_fu=New%20Enrollment%20Followup&nooppti=1&acclkid_lkid={!Lead.Existing_Account__c}&acclkid_lkwgt={!Lead.Existing_Account__c}
```

You have to specify AccountId 3 times.

Src: https://techman97.wordpress.com/tag/professional-edition/

Comment: Is there a way to predefine a field in lead conversion while using Lightning?

Comment: @JacobRaccuia Url hacks are back in Spring 20: https://thewizardnews.com/2020/01/27/url-hacks-are-back-and-in-lightning-with-spring-20/

Comment: it doesn't seem to support for lead conversion though, just for new objects